# Archlinux: can't build bazel java-tutorial

Tags: java, bazel, archlinux

### Environment

```sh
%bazel version
Build label: 4.2.0
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Aug 23 13:31:45 2021 (1629725505)
Build timestamp: 1629725505
Build timestamp as int: 1629725505

%env | grep JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default

%ls -l $JAVA_HOME
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun 18 22:33 /usr/lib/jvm/default -> java-16-openjdk
```

### Protocol

```sh
%git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples
%cd examples/java_tutorial
%bazel build //:ProjectRunner
                                                 
INFO: Analyzed target //:ProjectRunner (23 packages loaded, 511 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[6 / 7] [Prepa] Building ProjectRunner.jar (2 source files)
FATAL: bazel crashed due to an internal error. Printing stack trace:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.ParameterFile.writeContent(ParameterFile.java:118)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.ParameterFile.writeParameterFile(ParameterFile.java:111)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.CommandLines$ParamFileActionInput.writeTo(CommandLines.java:275)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.sandbox.SandboxHelpers.writeVirtualInputTo(SandboxHelpers.java:238)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.sandbox.SandboxHelpers.atomicallyWriteVirtualInput(SandboxHelpers.java:94)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.sandbox.SandboxHelpers$SandboxInputs.materializeVirtualInput(SandboxHelpers.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.sandbox.SandboxHelpers$SandboxInputs.access$100(SandboxHelpers.java:154)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.sandbox.SandboxHelpers.processInputFiles(SandboxHelpers.java:308)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.exec(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:182)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.SpawnRunner.execAsync(SpawnRunner.java:238)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.AbstractSpawnStrategy.exec(AbstractSpawnStrategy.java:144)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.AbstractSpawnStrategy.exec(AbstractSpawnStrategy.java:106)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.SpawnStrategy.beginExecution(SpawnStrategy.java:47)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.SpawnStrategyResolver.beginExecution(SpawnStrategyResolver.java:65)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.rules.java.JavaCompileAction.beginExecution(JavaCompileAction.java:357)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.Action.execute(Action.java:127)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$5.execute(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:855)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$ActionRunner.continueAction(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:1016)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$ActionRunner.run(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:975)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionState.runStateMachine(ActionExecutionState.java:129)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionState.getResultOrDependOnFuture(ActionExecutionState.java:81)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor.executeAction(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:472)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.checkCacheAndExecuteIfNeeded(ActionExecutionFunction.java:834)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.compute(ActionExecutionFunction.java:307)
    at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.AbstractParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run(AbstractParallelEvaluator.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.concurrent.AbstractQueueVisitor$WrappedRunnable.run(AbstractQueueVisitor.java:398)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make java.lang.String(byte[],byte) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @13e39c73
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unsafe.StringUnsafe.<init>(StringUnsafe.java:75)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unsafe.StringUnsafe.initInstance(StringUnsafe.java:56)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unsafe.StringUnsafe.<clinit>(StringUnsafe.java:37)
    ... 29 more
```

### Expected

The build pass

### Observed

The trace above...

Answer (score 2):

After digging a little, Archlinux package [jdk-openjdk](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jdk-openjdk/) which is Java 17 while bazel is built against JDK-11 so by "default" it will fail.

another way to fix it is to change the "JAVA_HOME" use:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk

bazel clean
bazel build //:ProjectRunner
```

note: You can also try to switch your env to JDK 11 using the helper script `archlinux-java`
ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/java#Switching_between_JVM

Answer (score 1):

You can likely work around this by passing the `--host_jvm_args=--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED` and `--host_jvm_args=--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` startup flags to Bazel.

It's probably worth filing a bug for the Arch package, since it's a distribution bug to not pass those flags.

Comment: after digging archlinux jdk-openjdk is Java 17 currently while bazel is built against JDK-11 so by "default" it will fail